# Weird sounds from your joints

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

English isn't my native language. I need some help. I look for a word to name a sound.

This sound you can hear when you bend your finger in opposite site.
This sound you can hear in your knees when you are doing squats.

I am trying to say something like this:
"I hear in my wrist (here name of this sound) when I am doing something"

Comment: the cracking of joints?

Comment: When you do it with your hands that's "cracking your knuckles".

Comment: I've also heard "popping" used before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *click* (British English) or *crack* (British and American English) various joints in your body including your knuckles, knees and elbows.

- [Clicking knuckles](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clicked+his+fingers%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=hZZ5V4SbI9TW8gey_KjQDg#q=%22clicked+his+knuckles%22)

  - Its owner clicked his knuckles nervously. (Terry Pratchett, *Small Gods*, 242)
  - [Do you click your knuckles?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAAPyPAxMdw)

Here is an excerpt from [the Wikipedia entry on  *Cracking Joints*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracking_joints):

> **Cracking joints**
>
> The act of cracking human joints happens when joint manipulation in humans produce a sharp cracking or popping sound. This occurs during deliberate knuckle-cracking, and it is possible to crack many other joints, such as those in the back and neck vertebrae, hips, wrists, elbows, shoulders, toes, ankles, knees, jaws, feet, sternum, and the Achilles tendon area. The mechanism that produces the cracking sound was until recently unknown.[1]
>
> According to a folk belief, the popping of joints, especially knuckles, leads to arthritis or other joint problems. However, medical research has so far failed to conclusively demonstrate any connection between knuckle cracking and long-term joint problems.

---

Joint cracking is one form of [*Crepitus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepitus)

Comment: There is also, of course, "creaking joints", the sound heard when I walk.